# Swager generates wrong example

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I try to create swagger documentation. I have this method's defenition:

```
@POST
@Operation(description = "Returns list of orders by some filters", tags = "Orders",
        requestBody = @RequestBody(content = @Content(
                schema = @Schema(type = "object", implementation = OrderDto.class)), required = true))
```

It is my `OrderDto` class:

```
@Data
public class OrderDto {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    @Schema(format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", example = "12/12/2000 00:00:00")
    private Date fromDate;
}
```

Swagger generates this result:

```
       "OrderDto": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "fromDate": {
                    "pattern": "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time"
                }
            }
        }
```

It looks like this:

[image]

But when I open the example value it looks like this:

[image]

I can not understand why. I have example and pattern: `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` but swagger generates its own example: `"2021-05-19T09:43:05.805Z"`

Answer (score 0):

According to OpenApi [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#pattern), the pattern should be a **regex** pattern.